# How to update bound values immediately in WPF DataGrid when editing cells?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, datagrid

I am working with a WPF DataGrid in an MVVM application. I have bound the DataGrid to an ObservableCollection in my ViewModel. Currently, when a user edits a cell in the DataGrid, the bound values only update when the cell loses focus.

Here is the XAML code for my DataGrid:

```xml
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding MyCollection}" AutoGenerateColumns="True">
</DataGrid>
```

My ViewModel looks similar to this:

```cs
public class MyViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public ObservableCollection<MyModel> MyCollection { get; set; } = new();
}
```

How can I make the bound values update immediately as the user edits the cells in the DataGrid?

Comment: This is a performance and convenience feature. The DataGrid modifies a temporary copy. The moment the cell loses focus and the cell leaves the edit mode, the edits are committed. If the user presses ESC the changes are discarded. You would have to override the complete edit logic. But why would you? Committing changes live is prone to unexpected behavior. imagine the user is editing a cell, while all changes are directly stored in the data model. Now the user decides to abort the editing and to discard the changes. You would have to manually track the changes in order to be able to undo them.

Comment: Usually the data of a DataTable is synchronized with a database. You don't want to update the database with incomplete data. Other clients that may use the same database would see the live editing, which is not what you want. Also you must guard against any modification of the edited data (outside the current editing process) until the edit is completed. Editing a copy is the most convenient way of editing a data object while supporting commit and discard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a very simple solution that works perfectly for my simple application by just changing the `UpdateSourceTrigger` of the editable column to `PropertyChanged`.

```xml
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding MyCollection}" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Column1" Binding="{Binding Path=Property1, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
        <!-- More columns if needed -->
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```